# An issue with a dropdown menu w/ embedded php content in a seperate location of the document

Tags: php

An issue with a dropdown menu. The problem isn't the menu code itself ie ul..etc, but a php chat program im currently embedding. After inserting this code to embed the chat box which appears with no errors the ability to use the ul dropdown link is disabled. The embedded php is in an entirely seperate div from the menu which is located in the #zonebar div.

the embedded code `<?php $chat->printChat(); ?>` which is in a specific div.

The thing is when i remove this code the dropdown menu buttons work again..

To be more specific the only php code in my html file with appropriate htaccess which allows me to use php in an html document is..

*the code below is located at the very top of my page above all tags*

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/src/phpfreechat.class.php";
$params = array();
$params["serverid"]       = md5(__FILE__); // calculate a unique id for this chat
$params["title"]          = "A simple chat with user's parameters";

$params["frozen_nick"]    = true;     // do not allow to change the nickname
$params["shownotice"]     = 0;        // 0 = nothing, 1 = just nickname changes, 2 = connect/quit, 3 = nick + connect/quit
$params["max_nick_len"]   = 20;       // nickname length could not be longer than 10 caracteres
$params["max_text_len"]   = 300;      // a message cannot be longer than 50 caracteres
$params["max_channels"]   = 1;        // limit the number of joined channels tab to 3
$params["refresh_delay"]  = 2000;    // chat refresh speed is 10 secondes (10000ms)
$params["max_msg"]        = 15;       // max message in the history is 15 (message seen when reloading the chat)
$params["height"]         = "230px";  // height of chat area is 230px

$params['admins'] = array('daddo'  => '1234', 'berthill' => '1234');
$params["debug"]          = false;     // activate debug console

$chat = new phpFreeChat( $params );

?>
```

*and then the code in the specific div*

```
<?php $chat->printChat(); ?>
```

*link directly the html file without any php content*
edited out address after fix

*link with the php code embedded*

Comment: Typically when you are embedding something you should check to see if it's adding additional JS or CSS that might overwrite what you have, and impact the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to wager a guess at this since looking through about a dozen javascript files is not something I really want to do.

Your dropdown menu uses jQuery... which is great.

Your chat uses Prototype... also great.

They are most likely not playing well together.  You can try doing this:

```
var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#zone-bar li em").click(function() {
        var hidden = $j(this).parents("li").children("ul").is(":hidden");
        $j("#zone-bar>ul>li>ul").hide()
        $j("#zone-bar>ul>li>a").removeClass();
        if (hidden) {
            $j(this)
            .parents("li").children("ul").toggle()
            .parents("li").children("a").addClass("zoneCur");
        }
    });
});
```

It may or may not work, but using `$j` instead of `$` may fix the issue.

Comment: Great fix sir..great timing as well. Once again thanks for the quick response and solution.. Time and time again stackoveflow has helped my coding experience.